# В Gulp при подключении плагина - gulp-webp-html-nosvg выдает ошибку Error: Callback called multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, gulp

Разрабатываю стандартную сборку Gulp, и столкнулся с такой проблемой. При подключении плагина
gulp-webp-html-nosvg вылетает ошибка Error: Callback called multiple times.

```
index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @@include('html/head.html',{
        "title":"Главная"
    })
    <body>
        @@include('html/header.html',{})
        <main>
            <img src="@img/cover.png">
        </main>
        @@include('html/footer.html',{})
    </body>
</html>
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "shop",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-file-include": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-webp-html-nosvg": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

```
html.js

import fileInclude from "gulp-file-include";
import webpHTML from "gulp-webp-html-nosvg";


export const html = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.html)
        .pipe(fileInclude())
        .pipe(app.plugins.replace(/@img\//g, 'img/'))
        .pipe(webpHTML())
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.html))
}
```

```
Ошибка

[03:24:24] Error: Callback called multiple times
    at Transform.afterTransform (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:82:31)     
    at Transform.fileInclude [as _transform] (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\lib\index.js:60:9)
    at Transform._read (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:177:10)
    at Transform._write (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:164:83)
    at doWrite (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:409:139)
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:398:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\gulp-file-include\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:307:11)     
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (C:\Users\serez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\shop\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:619:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:domain:537:15)
[03:24:24] 'default' errored after 150 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

В файле **html.js** следует поменять `.pipe(webpHTML())` на `.pipe(webpHtmlNosvg())`,

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Так он назвал так плагин webpHTML, это работать не будёт) думаю тут проблема у самого плагина, можно кинуть issue разработчику на гитхаб

Comment: Да, это конечно же не сработало. Но интересно то, что я попробовал поменять название плагина и ошибка поменялась на эту:  TypeError: PluginError is not a constructor

Comment: Тоже думаю, что это какой-то баг, напишу разраюотчику, посмотрим, что скажет